# Could someone please explain this block of code and what exactly it does?

Tags: c

This is only a part of the original program. We are calling the bSearch to perform a binary search recursively after the array is sorted 
How come the program has to return to -1?
Could I get a quick summary on what this block of code does and how it does it please.

```
int bSearch(int *arr, int a, int b, int key){
    if (b >= a){
        int mid = (b + a) / 2;
        if (*(arr + mid) == key)
            return mid;
        if (*(arr + mid) > key)
            return bSearch(arr, a, mid - 1, key);
        return bSearch(arr, mid + 1, b, key);
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

There should not be any error messages

Comment: It returns the index found, or -1 if it fails.

Comment: `int mid = (b + a) / 2;` can overflow. Also:the person who wrote this does not seem to know array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look up the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) first. Follow the algorithm with the comments in the code below

```
// arr => input array (sorted)
// a => left index to search from (initially 0)
// b = right index upto which to search (initially equals to length - 1)
// key => the value to find in the array
int bSearch(int *arr, int a, int b, int key){

    if (b >= a){
        // if the right index is greater than the left index
        // there is a chance that the key is between the indexes
        // search 5 in [1,4,6,7], if a = 0 and b = 3, 5 may be in the array


        int mid = (b + a) / 2;
        // divide your code from the middle, so the key is either in the left or the right side
        // this is guarenteed as the array is sorted


        if (*(arr + mid) == key)
            return mid;
        // if the place where we divide from contains the key, we have a match



        if (*(arr + mid) > key)
            return bSearch(arr, a, mid - 1, key);
        // if item in the middle is greater than the key
        // we only need to search in the left section [a to mid -1] (sorted array)


        return bSearch(arr, mid + 1, b, key);
        // else (if item in the middle is less than the key)
        // we only need to search in the right section [mid + 1 to b] (sorted array)
    }


    return -1; 
    // if the left index is greater than the right index, the key doesn't exist in the array
}
```

Comment: thank you for the comments and the link, reading up on it currently

Answer (score 0):

It is a binary search algorithm.

> How come the program has to return to -1?

Well, it doesn't have to:

```
int bSearch(int *arr, int a, int b, int key){
    if (b >= a){
        int mid = (b + a) / 2;
        if (*(arr + mid) == key)
            // the key was found! return it, this also stops any further recursion
            return mid;
        if (*(arr + mid) > key)
            return bSearch(arr, a, mid - 1, key);
        return bSearch(arr, mid + 1, b, key);
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters said, this is binary search. Most likely, the professor has hardcoded -1 as a "failure" value. If -1 is returned, the value is not in the structure.

Read more about binary search here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm